# Disable ANDROID compilation flag for one file

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to compile an executable binary to be packaged with my Java android application. The executable, VMD, has a main file vmdmain.C with the following

```cpp
#if defined(ANDROID)
int VMDmain(int argc, char **argv) {
# else
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#endif
```

It seems that the android ndk with cmake implicitly sets the ANDROID flag via `-DANDROID`. This causes the main function above to be defined as VMDmain instead. Of course, with no main function, the executable fails to link, giving the error:

```
/home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/crtbegin_dynamic.o:crtbegin.c:function _start_main: error: undefined reference to 'main'
```

---

**I therefore want to, for the file vmdmain.C only, unset the ANDROID flag**, so that the main function will be named main instead of VMDmain. I have tried in CMakeLists.txt

```
set_source_files_properties(src/main/vmd/vmd-1.9.3/src/vmdmain.C PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DANDROID=0)
```

where the `add_executable` directive in the same CMakeLists.txt file looks like

```
add_executable(
    vmd

    src/main/vmd/vmd-1.9.3/src/vmdmain.C
    # other files...
)
```

which results in the following entry in the "command" key for vmdmain.c in compile_commands.json (linebreaks added, some unrelated compile flags and includes, libs excluded for clarity):

```
/home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ \
  --target=i686-none-linux-android24 \
  --gcc-toolchain=/home/ning/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 \
  -DARCH_ANDROIDARMV7A \
  -DTCL_LIBRARY=\\\"/home/username/application/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86\\\" \
  -DTCL_PACKAGE_PATH=\\\"/home/username/application/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86\\\" \
  -DVMDMSMS \
  -DVMDNANOSHAPER \
  -DVMDPLUGIN_STATIC \
  -DVMDSURF \
  --sysroot /home/ning/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot \
  -g \
  -DANDROID \
  -fdata-sections \
  -ffunction-sections \
  -funwind-tables \
  -fstack-protector-strong \
  -no-canonical-prefixes \
  -fno-addrsig \
  -Wa,--noexecstack \
  -Wformat \
  -Werror=format-security \
  -stdlib=libc++ \
  -O0 \
  -fno-limit-debug-info \
  -fPIE \
  -DANDROID=0 \
  -o CMakeFiles/vmd.dir/src/main/vmd/vmd-1.9.3/src/vmdmain.C.o \
  -c /home/ning/github/palantir/app/src/main/vmd/vmd-1.9.3/src/vmdmain.C
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I still get the same `undefined reference to main` error.

Comment: Have you tried `-UANDROID` instead? But I really don't understand what prevents you from manually editing this **vmdmain.c** file.

Comment: @AlexCohn, thank you, using `-UANDROID` with `set_source_files_properties` works! I did not know of that option. Will you be willing to write this down as an answer, so I can accept it? I am refraining from editing this file, because my build process pulls it from version control, from an external repository.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're supposed to do? I don't know the library, but perhaps you're supposed to build a library and call VMDmain via JNI? An executable isn't much use on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a definition for C preprocessor, use

```
-UANDROID
```

It's true that

```
#if (ANDROID)
```

will work the same for `-DANDROID=0` and `-UANDROID`, but the following (equivalent) statements behave differently:

```
#if defined(ANDROID)
```

or

```
#ifdef ANDROID
```